# Sub-domain delegation in MyDNS, Pointing sub domain to another ns record

Tags: domain-name-system

I have been trying to delegate my sub-domain to another nameserver but cannot do it. I have read through all the documents and posts that might be helpful but still I cannot accomplish my task. What I have done so far:

mydomain.com in my ns1.myserver.com,ns2.myserver.com Which is running good.

Now I have used "MyDNS" for the management of the all the DNS Records.

What I tried is:

```
subdomain.mydomain.com IN NS ns1.anotherserver.com.
subdomain.mydomain.com IN NS ns2.anotherserver.com.
ns1.anotherserver.com. IN A 1.2.3.4
ns2.anotherserver.com. IN A 1.2.3.5
```

But that system isn't working out. Can anyone help me? Do not worry about TTL and others, every thing is managed. Is the subdomain delegation correct? Anyone experienced with MyDNS?

Please just answer with:

```
subdomain.mydomain.com IN A 1.2.3.4
subdomain.mydomain.com IN A 1.2.3.5
```

I want a better solution than above. Its not the thing that it can't be done right?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to wil tan
The record at is valid:

```
dig @ns1.anotherserver.com subdomain.mydomain.com SOA
```

I checked the record on my own server side as:

```
dig @ns1.myserver.com subdomain.mydomain.com SOA
```

and found that the record returned "subdomain.mydomain.com.mydomain.com" which caused the problem. Once again thanks for the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that "subdomain.mydomain.com" only has the two NS records you listed.
2. Make sure that "ns1.anotherserver.com" does exist. Check that `dig ns1.anotherserver.com` returns an IP address
3. Make sure that "ns1.anotherserver.com" is configured with the "subdomain.mydomain.com" zone, and is answering queries for it. (Check that `dig @ns1.anotherserver.com subdomain.mydomain.com SOA` returns a valid SOA record)

Note that you do not need these two lines in your zone file:

```
ns1.anotherserver.com. IN A 1.2.3.4
ns2.anotherserver.com. IN A 1.2.3.5
```

because they are out of zone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I configured every thing like that.
1) have only 2 records
2) dig nameserver do exists
3) and ns1.anotherserver.com is also nicely configured.

But when I try to just set with
NS in ns1.anotherserver.com and ns2.anotherserver.com

"nslookup subdomain.mydomain.com" replies none :/

For testing I added as:
subdomain in NS ns1,ns2
subdomain in A 1.2.3.4(IP of ns1)

And it works, but the problem is I guess it is only getting the value of A record and NS isn't getting anything.

Comment: WOW!!! Thanks, you are really awesome. Thanks for the command "dig [at]ns1.anotherserver.com subdomain.mydomain.com". What I did is "dig [at]ns1.myserver.com subdomain.mydomain.com" and found that the record for the domain using NS record was set as "subdomain.mydomain.com.mydomain.com" what made the problem whole along. Thank you very very much for the awesome solution. Have a nice day.
Just made the change to:
subdomain IN NS ns1.anotherserver.com. &&
subdomain IN NS ns2.anotherserver.com.